# Establishing Telnet through SSH connection

Tags: c#, sockets, ssh, telnet, ssh.net

I am writing a tool that needs to connect SSH first, then open a Telnet with credentials. Manually from Putty I can connect SSH then run command;

```
telnet localhost 21000
```

This asks me credentials. But when I do this in code, there is nothing happened. I have tried MinimalisticTelnet but it established telnet from my machine. I dont want to this. Telnet connection has to be done on SSH connection.

Here is my code;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Renci.SshNet;
using MinimalisticTelnet;

namespace Ssh_Net
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String host = "54.88.81.210";
            String username = "root";
            String password = "abcd1234";
            int port = 22;

            ForwardedPortDynamic tunnelPort;

            // Setup SSH with Credentials
            ConnectionInfo ConnNfo = new ConnectionInfo(host, port, username,

                new AuthenticationMethod[] {

                        /* Password based authentication */
                        new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(username, password)
                }
            );


            // Instantly execute a shell command

            using (var sshclient = new SshClient(ConnNfo))
            {
                sshclient.Connect();
                Console.WriteLine("Connecting");

                if (sshclient.IsConnected)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(sshclient.RunCommand("telnet localhost 21000").Execute());

                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.Write(e.ToString());
                    }
                }

                Console.ReadLine();
                sshclient.Disconnect();

            }


        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After each `shell.writeline`, put a

```
system.threading.sleep(1500)
```

to give it time to prompt for username and password.

Answer (score 0):

I've the same issue.
This is what I do

```
sshMaster = new SshClient(host, sshUserSSL, sshPwdSSL);
sshMaster.Connect();
ShellStream shell = sshMaster.CreateShellStream("master", 80, 24, 800, 600, 1024);
shell.WriteLine(" telnet localhost 21000");
shell.WriteLine(USERNAME);
shell.WriteLine(PASSWORD);
```

I can read the telnet prompt, with the Username and Password request, but when I sending username and password seems doesn't work